# How to set HStack spacing From Length to CGFloat in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

After updating Xcode 11 beta 5 I am unable to set HStack spacing and frame. Because it ask me to set it in CGFloat.
I tried CGFloat(100) but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Xcode often reports that error when the problem lies elsewhere. You aren't using isSheetShowing in your actionSheet maybe you should change the type of acitionSheet to isPresenting. The definition of isPresenting isn't shown but it needs to be optional to match the definition of item.

Comment: @MichaelSalmon Thanks! It's Working